# BrowserWindowOpener close event

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have such code

```
printWindow = new BrowserWindowOpener(invoicesBeanService.getHTMLStream());     printWindow.setFeatures("menubar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=900");
printWindow.extend(this.button_2);
```

How can I detect close event of `BrowserWindowOpener` when I close the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Add click listener to the button

```
Button button_2 = new Button("Close");
button_2.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        close();
    }
});
printWindow.extend(button_2);
layout.addComponent(button_2);
```

Comment: To simple to be truth :). When the main window is closed button_2 is deattached from printwindow and resource connector to printWindow is lost which results in resource deletion (dynamic html report)